# How to reduce the space between the table cells

Tags: ios, swift4.2

The content in the cells is aligned to the center.
This caused the cells were separated by unwanted white space.

I have tried the following code

In viewDidLoad

```
 tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
 tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
 tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

In cellForRowAt

```
 cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
 cell.separatorInset = .zero
```

I am looking for a utility method to customize the space between the cells.

Please find the image below

[Cell row height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpmxE.jpg)

Comment: post your image of tableviewcell

Answer (score 1):

Cells have exactly `0` space between them, so the cells themselves have to have a top/bottom margins.

To simply test what I've just said, set background of the cell to `.red`. If I'm wrong, you will have white stripes between red cells.

To get it right:

- Look for top/bottom margins/constraints inside the cell and remove them
- Make sure that all constraints make the row height unambiguous and use `automaticDimension` or calculate row height by yourself and hardcode it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview?language=objc). This lets you set the size regardless of the content in your cell.

Comment: This is good only when we have a static fixed text. However, in my case, the content in the cell varies by number of lines

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your cell configuration, maybe setting `automaticDimension` could resolve it:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Otherwise, you may want to decrease the cell height:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CELL_HEIGHT_VALUE
}
```

Hope this helps.